# How to obtain odds ratio (and 95% CI) from ridge regression model

Tags: logistic, predictive-models, regularization, ridge-regression

I am currently working on a ridge logistic (predictive) model. I was able to complete most of the steps and obtain the coefficient but I keep getting an error message when it comes to the **odds ratio** & **95% CI**. Can someone please help me fix the following R code (**especially the last line**)?

Here is my code for ridge regression:

```
x <- model.matrix(disease ~ percentage + SmokingNA, final)[,-1]
y <- final$disease
library(glmnet)
set.seed(123) 
cv <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, family = "binomial")
# Display the best lambda value
cv$lambda.min
model <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, lambda = cv$lambda.min, family = "binomial")
# Display regression coefficients
coef(model)
exp(cbind(OR = coef(model), confint(model)))
```

The last line results in the following error message:

*Error in UseMethod("vcov") : no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an
object of class "c('lognet', 'glmnet')*

Below is my data:

```
structure(list(percentage = c(5.5, 72.1, 7.9, 80.6, 56.3, 11.5, 
15.3, 12.3, 30.9, 27.5, 0.3, 5.3, 19.6, 19.8, 0.3, 40.5, 16.8, 
38, 13.8, 29.9, 15.8, 15.3, 22.8, 17.2, 41.2, 17.2, 31.6, 41.2, 
19.6, 38, 41.2, 29.9, 15.3, 29.9, 38, 30.9, 31.6, 15.3, 15.3, 
38, 31.6, 41.3, 21.4, 0.4, 41.2, 7.6, 29.9),  
    SmokingNA = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("non-smoking", 
    "smoking"), class = "factor"), disease = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("none", "disease"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-47L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

The error says that glmnet doesn't have a `vcov` method so it can't compute confidence intervals.  Not that you would want to anyway, the (intentional) bias would mean the confidence intervals would likely not have the appropriate coverage probability (if they covered the estimand at all).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. So, how about the odds ratio? Can you please show me how I can obtain the OR?

Comment: @RBeginner You've done it correctly by exponentiating the coefficients

Comment: Got it! so we cannot report 95% CI from ridge regression at all? Or is there another (more appropriate) way to do it?

Comment: @RBeginner There is some research surrounding valid inference for penalized models, but generally classic statistics don't apply because the estimates are no longer unbiased.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you pls explain again why we won't need to report 95% CI from ridge regression in a lay language (I have a hard time understanding bias/unbias concept you referred to)?

Comment: @RBeginner Estimates from GLMs are the parameters which minimize some loss function (here the negative loglikelihood).  Those parameters and the fact they are the minimizers are essential for having confidence intervals with the desired coverage (95% of the time they are constructed, they cover the estimand within the interval).  Because of the penalization glmnet uses (the `lambda`), the coefficients are no longer the minimizers and the relationship between confidence intervals is not met.

Comment: @RBeginner The coefficients are purposefully smaller than they would otherwise be, and this would be the case across many datasets.  This tendency for the coefficients to be smaller is called bias.  The bias is the reason we can't use confidence intervals.